# Non-inferiority testing without normal approximation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, non-inferiority

I am performing a non-inferiority test on two binomial trials. I want to determine if my test proportion, pT, is not worse than my control, pC, by more than an amount d. Assuming nT trials of my test and nC trials of my control, the standard statistic for such a test is given by ([da Silva 2009](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2701110/))
$$
z = \frac{pT - pC + d}{\sqrt{\frac{pT(1-pT)}{nT} + \frac{pC(1-pC)}{nC}}},
$$
which is distributed according to a standard normal distribution. However, this equation assumes that the binomial distributions generated by (pT, nT) and (pC, nC) are approximately Gaussian. My test and control proportions are both very close to one so this approximation doesn't hold. Is there a way of performing such a test exactly using the actual binomial distributions?